# Trouble when writing RewriteRule in apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current url is like `news/sometopics/newstitle.html`.

And I want url like this `sometopics/newstitle.html`.

Why is the following not working?

```
RewriteRule ^(.+/)(.+).html$ news/$1/$2.html
```

By the way, I am using GoDaddy Apache server. This rule:

```
RewriteRule ^search/$  admin/plus/search.php
```

works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule will match only alphanumeric strings such as: `titlenews123`. I prefer it over the generic match everything meta-char `(.+)`

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-]+)/([0-9a-z-]+).html$ news/$1/$2.html [L]
```

If your `sometopics` and `newstitle` are not only alphanumeric you can do (discouraged)

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+).html$ news/$1/$2.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. But it is still not working. According to the error message, it does not match at first place.My test case is "http://mydomains.com/test/a.html". And my real url could have "-" like new/ebola-virus.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why ^([^/]+)/([^/]+).html$ news/$1/$2.html [L] is discouraged? Would there be a efficency problem? Thanks a lot!